# How to convert *x509.Certificate into byte slice in Go

Tags: go, certificate, x509certificate, x509

I've a certificate

```golang
cert := parseCert("cert.pem") // returns *x509.Certificate
```

Need to convert that `cert` into `[]byte` so I can do the thing I want to do which requires byte slice of a certificate, like the following returns

```golang
certByte, _ := x509.CreateCertificate(...) // returns []byte (it's not PEM encoded, need like this)
```

How this can be done?

Comment: [x509.CreateCertificate documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#CreateCertificate)  says "The returned slice is the certificate in DER encoding.  [x509.Certificate](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#Certificate) has a field `Raw []byte // Complete ASN.1 DER content (certificate, signature algorithm and signature)`.  That might be what you want.

Comment: Is it exactly what is returned by `x509.CreateCertificate`?

Comment: Read the doc I linked; my quote was verbatim.